# Unmounting Linux

Tags: kali-linux, fsck

I have a problem with `hashcat` in Kali Linux and someone on the Internet suggested to do fsck. I check and it says to unmount the device before using the fsck command. I am using Kali Linux in dual boot with Windows 10 and when in Kali I used command `sudo fdisk -l` I get

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1944CA1D-BEC1-4BB5-BE09-9B95435D98AE

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery 
environment
/dev/sda2      923648    1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1126400    1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1159168  817444121 816284954 389.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   817444864  819197951   1753088   856M Windows recovery 
environment
/dev/sda6   819200000 1372157951 552957952 263.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1372160000 1797947391 425787392   203G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  1797947392 1920043007 122095616  58.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1920043008 1953523711  33480704    16G Linux swap
```

and it shows me this list. Can you please list the commands to input now to unmount the partition that is damaged and use fsck command on that? I am unable to unmount the `sda8` because it’s in use as I am using the command window in this only.  How do I perform the further steps?

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/47953/can-i-run-fsck-or-e2fsck-when-linux-file-system-is-mounted

Comment: for people marking this question as below your genius level. I am a masters in electrical engineering and trying to learn this as a hobby by online tutorials and trial and error, you people just don't want to help anybody who isn't already an expert in this. Being on a help forum and denying help, so much for hypocrisy. But you should worry because there are still some people who wants to help those in need.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the output of `df -h` or `mount`, I don't know for sure where your `/dev/sda8` is mounted. However, because it appears to be your only Linux filesystem, I guess it is the root filesystem of your Linux installation.

Checking the root filesystem requires special steps, because you cannot just unmount your root filesystem: you would then have no filesystem available where to load the `fsck` tool from!

However, you might be able to remount it read-only, with `mount -o remount,ro /`. Then you could run `fsck.ext4 -C0 -f /dev/sda8`. But switching the root filesystem into read-only mode when the complete operating system is up and running would generate a lot of errors, and if the `fsck` command made any changes to the disk contents, you would have to intentionally crash the system and reboot after the `fsck` was complete, as the data in operating system's buffers would now be out of sync with the true state of the disk. So this procedure is not recommended.

The right way to run a `fsck` on the root filesystem is to boot the system into single-user mode. One way to do this is to add boot options like `init=/bin/bash` while in the GRUB bootloader. This should put your system into a state where the root filesystem is in read-only mode and no background daemons are started, and you could probably just run `fsck -C0 -f /dev/sda8` and when it has completed, run `reboot` to restart the system in normal mode.

("Should" and "probably" are there because I don't know the details of Kali's single user mode. There might be some extra steps required.)

Comment: Thanks a lot telcoM, you still tried to help me despite everyone else critisizing me. And your answer solved my problem.